# Exception (stack trace) in one line

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm using Nlog for debug /info / Exception . its working fine but issue is when I log exception it logs stack trace on new line.

Can some one help me how to get it one line, layout I'm using:

```xml
<target xsi:type="File" name="default" layout="${longdate} -- [${level:uppercase=true}] -- ${message} ${onexception:${newline}EXCEPTION OCCURED\: ${exception:format=ToString}}" 
        fileName="${basedir}/logs/logfile.txt" keepFileOpen="false" 
        archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/archive/logfile_${shortdate}.{##}.log"
        archiveNumbering="Sequence" archiveEvery="Day" maxArchiveFiles="30" />
```

I'm trying to write a small viewer that will read log.txt and reading line by line with some placeholders so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If the stacktrace isn't mandatory for you, then you can change the `format` to `message`

Comment: You can extend NLog and customize renderer to write the log the way you want. http://nlog-project.org/2015/06/30/extending-nlog-is-easy.html or https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Replace-NewLines-Layout-Renderer

Comment: Did my answer worked?

Answer (score 2):

The `ToString` format is the default .NET format with newlines. You could replace them with `${replace-newlines` but it's a bit hacky. It would look like this:

`${replace-newlines:${exception:format=ToString}}}`,

A better option is to list the properties you need and set the separator. All options for [${exception} are listed at NLog's wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Exception-Layout-Renderer). Example:

`${exception:format=message,type,method,stacktrace:innerExceptionSeparator=|:separator:,maxInnerExceptionLevel=10}`

PS: `maxInnerExceptionLevel` is not required here, but advised to set as the default is 0.

Comment: it doesnt work i have tried both option s  ${replace-newlines:${exception:format=ToString}}

Comment: ${exception:format=message,type,method,stacktrace:innerExceptionSeparator=|:separator:,maxInnerExceptionLevel=10}

Comment: The exception stack trace has usually new lines, so the only solution is to use `${replace-newlines}`.

${replace-newline